# C++/CPP Reading an added hex address

Tags: c++, winapi, readprocessmemory

I'm still relatively new-ish to CPP but I can't find any source that has my issue.  My IDE is MSVC 2017 Preview and my desired outcome is to add two hex addresses together, then read the address' value.  I'm not sure why but it's not playing nicely with adding hex numbers.  I'll give you my current example:

```
int number;
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(0x37c90000 + 0xE29FE8), &number, sizeof(number), 0);
std::cout << number << " for " << std::hex << (0x37c90000 + 0xE29FE8) << std::endl;

ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (void*)(0x38ab9fe8), &number, sizeof(number), 0);
std::cout << number << " for " << std::hex << (0x38ab9fe8) << std::endl;

std::cout << "a = " << (0x37c90000 + 0xE29FE8) << std::endl;
std::cout << "b = " << (0x38ab9fe8) << std::endl;
```

My predicted outcome of this code would be that both ReadProcessMemory should get the same exact same value, but instead only the second ReadProcessMemory (with the already added hex value) returns properly.

Furthermore, cout-ing A and B report the **exact same** address.  If that's the case, why is ReadProcessMemory throwing a tantrum and reporting a negative number on the first ReadProcessMemory?

Here's my outcome with the code above:

```
-331287296 for 38ab9fe8
ec40f500 for 38ab9fe8
a = 38ab9fe8
b = 38ab9fe8
```

Apologies but I truly can't figure out why they're different in any way.

Comment: They are the same, if you convert the hex to signed int. Though, I can't figure out the reason for discrepancy

Comment: That's like looking up Alice and Bob in the phone book, and adding their phone numbers together. You can do it, but it hardly seems worth the effort.

Comment: The end goal was to add a (base) address with offsets to get a multi level pointer.  Is there a better solution apart from just adding addresses and reading the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that seems about right. `0xec40f500` is the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the decimal signed value `-331287296`. Please learn about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation of negative numbers.

The problem is, I believe, the `std::hex` [manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), which is *sticky*. If you in the second case use `std::dec` both numbers will be displayed as decimal:

```
// Second output
std::cout << std::dec << number << " for " << std::hex << (0x38ab9fe8) << std::endl;
//           ^^^^^^^^
// Display *all* following numbers as decimal
```

Or use `std::hex` in the first output:

```
// First output
std::cout << std::hex << number << " for " << (0x37c90000 + 0xE29FE8) << std::endl;
//           ^^^^^^^^
// Display *all* following numbers as hexadecimal
```

---

Of course, if you intend for `number` to be unsigned, you need to explicitly say so when defining the variable. Perhaps it would be easier for you to see the connection between `0xec40f500` and the *unsigned* decimal value `3963680000`?

Comment: Wonderful, I can't believe that flew over my head.  Thank you for the clarity.  I honestly can't believe that flew over my head even though I knew it was something simple.